# Finding the Inverse of this function

Tags: functions, inverse

Im trying to find the inverse of this function

> $$x \mapsto\frac {113^x - 1}{112}\def\comment#1{}\comment{(pow(113.0, x)-1.0)/112.0} $$

But it always turn up incorrect.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: In what way does it "turn up incorrect" ? Have you tried solving $y = \frac {113^{\ x} - 1}{112}$ for $x$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y=\frac{113^x-1}{112}$$
$$112y+1=113^x$$
$$x\log 113=\log(112y+1)$$
$$x=\frac{\log(112y+1)}{\log 113}$$